# Which SoC for making a Rubik's Cube Solver?

Tags: raspberry-pi2, intel-galileo, rubiks-cube

Is it wiser to use a Raspberry Pi over an Intel Galileo for making a Rubik's Cube Solver? Programming language isn't a major issue, Although Python would be slightly more preferred.

The major constraint is that there is only one PWM pin on the Raspberry Pi, we're thinking about using servo motors to rotate the Cube. What do you people think?

Major differences:

- PWM pins
- Processor
- RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is hardly the kind of question to ask on this forum; I will attempt to NOT confuse you with my answer.
Before trying to answer which is best there are a few other things you need to ask yourself:

1. what does your design involve other than the processor? Do you want
   to use 6 servos, one for each face of the cube? Do you have a more
   cost efficient design that involves fewer servos? How many I/O pins
   do you actually need?
2. RAM and Processor type are factors to consider when it comes to how fast your algorithm will run. Are you trying to make the fastest Rubik's Cube Solver in the world? Or just one that can actually solve the problem.
3. is cost a factor? Both platforms are decently priced but there is a difference between them which may matter when you are on a budget
4. The Galileo platform is newer than the Pi. You are more likely to find answers to your question when going with the more popular platform.
5. Is the programming language important? This comes back to how fast you want the algorithm to run. A c implementation will run faster than a python implementation, but ultimately I think it's better to stick to what you are more comfortable with.

On a personal note, I would probably go with the Pi because there's a huge  community built around it and you can find plug-in expansion boards for almost anything you can think of, which will allow you to focus on software without worrying too much about the hardware side of things.

Comment: My bad, I actually thought this was pretty appropriate.

1.We're using 4 servos, each of which are connected to a solenoid actuator. So I'm guessing 4 for the PWM pins? and 4 GPIO ones for the actuators? (Assuming the servo+solenoid combo works)

2. It just has to solve it in a decent time.

3. Cost isn't a problem, our institute will be providing us with the required board.

5. Programming language isn't a major factor, I would prefer C over python, but according our project guidelines Python should be our first choice. ( Isn't a compulsion)

I agree, but what about the PWM pins?

Comment: you can emulate a PWM using GPIO pins if you find you need more tha you have available. I'm also not sure how you are going to solve the cube with 4 servos; the cube has 6 sides that need to rotate; every solver I've seen, even the current world record holder uses 6 servos.